# problem with installing Tor on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, proxy

I tried to install tor in terminal by:

```
sudo apt-get install tor
```

and this is the output:

```
> Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
tor is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up tor (0.2.2.35-1) ...
Raising maximum number of filedescriptors (ulimit -n) to 32768.
Starting tor daemon: tor...
ABORTED: Tor configuration invalid:
May 02 12:31:09.978 [notice] Tor v0.2.2.35 (git-73ff13ab3cc9570d). This is experimental software. Do not rely on it for strong anonymity. (Running on Linux i686)
May 02 12:31:09.978 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Unknown option 'ClientTransportPlugin'.  Failing.
May 02 12:31:09.978 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
invoke-rc.d: initscript tor, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing tor (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tor-geoipdb:
 tor-geoipdb depends on tor (>= 0.2.2.35-1); however:
  Package tor is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing tor-geoipdb (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 tor
 tor-geoipdb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

so, can anyone help me to fix it plz!? :|

Thanx @MrSeed ! I tried to remove by:

`sudo apt-get remove tor`

and the output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  tor tor-geoipdb
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 6,361 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 396092 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing tor-geoipdb ...
Removing tor ...
Stopping tor daemon: not running (there is no /var/run/tor/tor.pid).
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for man-db ...
```

and then install again by:

`sudo apt-get install tor`

and output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  tor-geoipdb
Suggested packages:
  mixmaster xul-ext-torbutton socat tor-arm polipo privoxy
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  tor tor-geoipdb
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,868 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,361 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Selecting previously unselected package tor.
(Reading database ... 396065 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking tor (from .../tor_0.2.2.35-1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package tor-geoipdb.
Unpacking tor-geoipdb (from .../tor-geoipdb_0.2.2.35-1_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Setting up tor (0.2.2.35-1) ...
Raising maximum number of filedescriptors (ulimit -n) to 32768.
Starting tor daemon: tor...
ABORTED: Tor configuration invalid:
May 02 19:54:07.679 [notice] Tor v0.2.2.35 (git-73ff13ab3cc9570d). This is experimental software. Do not rely on it for strong anonymity. (Running on Linux i686)
May 02 19:54:07.679 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Unknown option 'ClientTransportPlugin'.  Failing.
May 02 19:54:07.679 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
invoke-rc.d: initscript tor, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing tor (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tor-geoipdb:
 tor-geoipdb depends on tor (>= 0.2.2.35-1); however:
  Package tor is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing tor-geoipdb (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 tor
 tor-geoipdb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

unfortunately the same error! :'(

Comment: It's better to use [tor browser bundle](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) as the version of tor in the repos is very old.

Answer (score 1):

So seems that my first option did not work here's option 2:

As @Mik mentioned *It's better to use tor browser bundle as the version of tor in the repos is very old.*

So what you want to do is:

1. Download Tor Brownser Bundle from here (If asked open with or save as choose save as.) --> [Tor Browser Bundle](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en)
2. When your download is complete open the location where you downloaded it. (Probable in `/home/<username>/Downloads`)
3. Unzip the file: right click on file -> Extract Here
4. Open the Extracted folder.
5. In the Extracted folder you will see a file named *start-tor-browser*. Open that file by double clicking on it and say run and not run in Terminal.
6. After that follow the steps as provided by tor.

For more Information and How to's:

[Installation Linux](https://media.torproject.org/video/torbrowser-docs/How-to-download-and-use-TBB-in-Linux.mp4)

[Verify you have the right version of Tor Browser Bundle](https://media.torproject.org/video/torbrowser-docs/How-to-verify-signatures-in-Linux.mp4)

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution for you , download tor from third party websites like :

```
http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Proxy/Tor-Browser-Bundle-2845.shtml
```

extract the .tar.gz into your home folder right click start tor and set execute as program . set necessary permissions and run the program . and it will work alright.

Comment: Thankx bro @Mahyar . . .
I have "Tor Browser Bundle", but I want to install and run Tor in terminal, to use commands like: torify . . .

Comment: If you start tor it should prompt you to either start it in Terminal or just run... you should then pick the Run in Terminal option.

Comment: Yes do as MrSeed said , run in terminal option let you enter commands after executing .